# how do you get the html and value output to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

given this html input element,  <input id="input1" type="text" />

if the user enters a value of 'test', is there a way in jQuery to serialize that to a string?

The output I would be looking for is, <input id="input1" type="text" value="test" />

I am not copying this to another element in DOM, I need the actual string so I can send it to EVOPdf.  I've already tried the clone(true), but it doesn't give me any values the user has entered into the inputs.

I'm resigned to having to parse the html() string and insert a value for each input unless someone knows a better way.

Comment: Do you mean the output you would be looking for is `<input id="input1" type="text" value="test" />` or just `test`?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: the output I'm looking for needs to be '<input id="input1" type="text" value="test" />',

Comment: its not a duplicate, outerHTML still doesn't have the values input by end user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I my testing, it turns out that the *attribute* value has nothing to do with the *value* value - at least in my testing with Safari 5.1 and FF 6.

So, if I modified the contents of a text field (I typed ueoau) and select it

```
> var text = $('input[type=text]').first()
```

and get its value using `.val()`

```
> text.val()
"ueoau"
```

but getting it's markup gets the value rendered as empty(this snippet from james' answer)

```
> $('<div>').append(text.clone()).remove().html()
"<input autocomplete="off" name="q" class="textbox" placeholder="search" tabindex="1" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="" style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px; ">"
```

getting the *attribute* value also doesn't work(using the DOM `getAttribute` here to avoid jQuery's magic in `attr()`)

```
> text[0].getAttribute('value')
""
```

So again, the *attribute* value is not the same as the *value* value. So, one workaround you could use is setting its attribute *to* its value

```
> text[0].setAttribute('value', text.val())
> $('<div>').append(text.clone()).remove().html()
"<input autocomplete="off" name="q" class="textbox" placeholder="search" tabindex="1" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="ueoau" style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px; ">"
```

Which worked for me. I guess my explanation for this is that the *attribute* value only stands for the initial value of the field, and is not synced with its true value afterwards.

Comment: Only `firebug` (don't know how this utility is called in Safari) returns html with all attributes (like in your code) but in real code - it will return html without attributes that weren't pointed in html mark-up

Comment: it took me a while, but I got this to work.  below is my code with comments where needed.

Comment: I'll try again, here's my code

var tempobj = $(getSelectedTab()).clone();

var inputarr = tempobj.find('input[type=text]').get();

$.each(inputarr, function (i) {

 var iid = $(inputarr[i]).attr('id');

 var v = $(inputarr[i]).val();

 tempobj.find('#'+iid).attr('value', v);

});

var s = tempobj.html();

Comment: Does not work with textareas, selects, etc., all the other elements that $(x).val('...') automatically handles. =\

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the `.val()` method which returns the value of an input:

```
var value = $("#input1").val();
```

For the html of the element itself (including value), try encapsulating a clone inside a new element, get the html, and delete it:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#input1').clone()).remove().html();
```

Comment: I know that, what I need is this:  <input id="input1" type="text" value="test" />

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="text">
<input type="button" id="foo" value="press me">
```

jQuery:

```
// fullHTML plugin-function

$.fn.fullHTML = function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    return $('<div>')  
                   .append($this.clone())
                   .remove()
                   .html()
                   .replace('<input ','<input value="'+ $this.val() +'" ');
};

$(function(){    
    $("#foo").click(function(){
        alert ( $("#test").fullHTML() );
    });
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n6Phu/

**P.S.** This code works only for inputs and it catches only `value` attribute pointed by user. Other attributes won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
var fragment = $("#input1").attr("value", "test").get(0).outerHTML;
```

Note than like .html() this will return interpreted markup; IE for example will capitalize node names & strip the quotes

Comment: The markup in that output also does not give the current value in the text field.

Comment: This doesn't actually work...  I can't get this to return anything other than `undefined`.

Comment: Wow, jquery has spoiled me, I had forgotten outerHTML was a no-no in Firefox, I only checked chrome+IE

Answer (score 0):

Need to use outerHTML() 
http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/

Comment: That solves absolutely nothing.  The problem is not MISSING ELEMENTS, the problem is MISSING ATTRIBUTES.